# select surronded by fieldset

Tags: html, css

How can I get a design that looks like this:

[image]

Tried a `select` in a `fieldset`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
legend{margin:-20px 0;}
select{margin-top:20px; border:0;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form>
 <fieldset>
  <legend>Auswahl</legend>
    <select>
    <option>Option1</option>
    <option>Option2</option>
    </select>
 </fieldset>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

The fieldset element is too big. It should lool like one element

Comment: Is there a bootstrap solution also?

Answer (score 1):

**You can try with the below code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.row{
  display: flex;
  column-gap: 15px;
}
.form-select{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding:10px 15px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 400;
    outline: none;
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
}
.custom-select{
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 0 0 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.custom-select:before{
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 6px solid transparent;
  border-right: 6px solid transparent;
  border-top: 6px solid #CCCCCC;
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: 2px;
}
.custom-select label{
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #FFF;
  color: #333;
  font-family: Arial;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
.form-select:focus{
  border: 1px solid #55935B;
}
.form-select:focus + label{
  color:#55935B;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<div class="row">

  <div class="custom-select">
    <select class="form-select">
      <option>Option1</option>
      <option>Option2</option>
    </select>
    <label>Auswahl</label>
  </div>

  <div class="custom-select">
    <select class="form-select">
      <option>Option1</option>
      <option>Option2</option>
    </select>
    <label>Jahr</label>
  </div>

</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

this one works

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
    form{
         display: flex;
         flex-direction: row;
         align-items: center;
         justify-content: space-around;
         width: 40vw;
         height: 10vh;
         background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.01);
         margin: 0 auto;
      }
 fieldset{
     width:16vw;
     height:3vh;
 background-color: white;
 border-radius: 10px;
 }
 legend{
    margin:-10px 0;
    }
 select{
    width: 16vw;
    height: 3vh; 
    border:0; }
 option{
     width: 100%
     }


</style>
</head>
<body>
<form>
 <fieldset>
  <legend class="legend">Auswahl</legend>
    <select>
    <option>Option1</option>
    <option>Option2</option>
    </select>
 </fieldset>
 <fieldset>
    <legend class="legend">Jahr</legend>
      <select>
      <option>Option1</option>
      <option>Option2</option>
      </select>
   </fieldset>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using "min-width" you can set same width of your both select box.

```css
fieldset {
    min-width: 150px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px 15px 11px 15px;
     display: inline-block;
}

select {
    margin-top: 15px;
    width: 100%;
    outline: none;
   border:0;
}
legend{margin:-20px 0;}


fieldset:hover {
    border-color: #4caf50;
}

fieldset:hover  legend{
    color:#4caf50;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>

</style>
</head>
<body>
<form>
 <fieldset>
  <legend>Auswahl</legend>
    <select>
    <option>Option1</option>
    <option>Option2</option>
    </select>
 </fieldset>
  
   <fieldset>
  <legend>Jahr</legend>
    <select>
    <option>Option1</option>
    <option>Option2</option>
    </select>
 </fieldset>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
form {  display: flex; margin: -10px 100% 0 0;}
legend{margin:-20px 0; }
select{margin-top:20px; border:0;}
fieldset {margin-right: 80%;}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<form>
 <fieldset>
  <legend>Auswahl</legend>
    <select>
    <option>Option1</option>
    <option>Option2</option>
    </select>
 </fieldset>

 <fieldset>
  <legend>Jahr</legend>
    <select>
    <option>Option1</option>
    <option>Option2</option>
    </select>
 </fieldset>


</form>

</body>
</html>
```

I added a `margin-right: 80%;` to decrease the size of the `fieldset` to not take the entire row.
Then I added 2 fieldset's for Jahr and Auswahl, and in the form's css I added `display: flex` to align both of them in the same line, and then
Lastly I added a bit of margin top and right to really make them look like they're next to each other.